# Navigation controller inside TabViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am editing my question that i had programetically add the tabbar as shown below:-

```
FirstViewController *obj_FirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];     
SecondViewController *obj_SecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
ThirdViewController *obj_ThirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]; 
navigation1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_FirstViewController];  
navigation2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_SecondViewController];
navigation3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_ThirdViewController];
MainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
MainTabBar.delegate=self;
[MainTabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigation1,navigation2,navigation3,nil]];
MainTabBar.view.frame=self.view.frame;
MainTabBar.selectedIndex=0;
[self.view addSubview:MainTabBar.view]
```

By writing this in (void)viewDidLoad i got the 3 tab in my viewcontroller.But the problem is i want to set the name of the tab as

1. **Home**
2. **Favorites**
3. **About us**

I had tried by writing the below code:-

1. **obj_FirstViewController.tabBarItem.title=@"Home";**
2. **self.title = @"My View Controller";**

But this does not work - can anyone please help me how to do this programatically?  Where to write the line so that i get this 3 name in my tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I made it

1) I made a view controller with your tabbar 
2) added view controllers for each tab and a method to the tabbar view controller class: 
-(void)updateContentsWithViewController:(UIViewController *)insideViewController

the method is called when a tabbutton is pressed.

3) here is the code for the switching

```
- (void)updateContentsWithViewController:(UIViewController *)insideViewController {
//internalViewController is the viewController which you change 

[internalViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[internalViewController release];

internalViewController = [insideViewController retain];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:insideViewController];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[navController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 348)];
//frame I needed in my app .. can be changed 

[self.internalView addSubview: navController.view];
//navController is the property for the navigationController

[self.view sendSubviewToBack: self.internalView];
```

}

Comment: Thanks Toncean.But i m very sorry but i didnt get the answer.I want to dynamically add the tabcontroller(4 tab) in my rootviewcontroller and want to give the navigation to the specific viewcontroller page.Please give me the code for doing that

Answer (score 0):

its possible add tabBar in separate view controller which will be like rootview controller ,then in viewDidLoad of the root view controller assign the object of tabbar created to a appdelegate tabBar declared ...then use appdelegate tabbar for other navigation's alone .